# Obstruction for two subgroups to be conjugated by an automorphism

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, abstract-algebra

Altough this sounds as a very basic question, I didn't receive any answer on stack exchange and by people more knowledgeable than me

Take $p$ a prime number and $P$ an abelian finite $p$-group. Let $A,A'$ be subgroup of $P$ such that $A \simeq A'$ and $P/A \simeq P/A'$ as groups. Can I conclude that there is $\phi \in Aut(P)$ such that $\phi(A)=A'$?

Thanks in advance!

p.s:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476641/obstruction-to-be-conjugated-by-an-automorphism-for-subgroups-of-an-abelian-grou, here the MSE link

Comment: You should always provide a link to the MSE post.

Comment: My apologize! Link added

Comment: I didn't see your MSE post, because you didn't give it the group-theory tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! Yes sorry it was silly not to put the group theory tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will use additive notation, and let $Z_k = \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$ with addition mod $k$.

Let $P = Z_2 \oplus Z_4 \oplus Z_8$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the subgroups
$$A = \langle (1,1,0),(0,0,4) \rangle,$$ and $$B = \langle (1,0,0,), (0,2,2) \rangle.$$

Then $A \cong B \cong  G/A \cong G/B \cong Z_2 \oplus Z_4$.

The element $(0,0,4)$ of $A$ is a multiple of $4$ in $G$, but is not a multiple of $2$ in $A$ (it generates the direct summand of $A$ of order $2$).

But the only nonzero element of $B$ that is a multiple of $4$ in $G$ is $(0,0,4)$, and this is a  multiple of $2$ in $B$. So no automorphism of $G$ can map $A$ to $B$.

I expect the same construction will work with any prime $p$ in place of $2$,